# How to access the stored procedure that are created inside the Package?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

I have managed to setup and run EF5 with ODP.NET and it works like charm. However, I am facing an issue with accessing Oracle stored procedures created inside the package. I am not able to see the procedure from the Entity Framework 5, in the .EDMX file. The procedure which are not inside the package can be added and accessed.

Is there some setting required to make this possible?

I am getting following error upon clicking Package in the Server Explorer: ORA-00904: "SELTAB"."OBJECT_TYPE": Invalid identifier

See this image http://postimg.org/image/qfs93q9ap/

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 12.1 requires Oracle Database 10.2.0.3 or later. The error you are seeing is caused because the OBJECT_TYPE identifier is not introduced until version 10.2.0.3 of the database.

Comment: Here is the database information:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Prod , I have installed Oracle client 12 and ODAC 12 with ODP.NET. When I click on the Package inside server explorer I get following error "ORA-00904: "SELTAB"."OBJECT_TYPE": Invalid identifier

Comment: Thanks. I looked up the details for this and modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks Christian, I cannot test this as I am not in a situation to upgrade database. But its a relief to know what the issue is.